# How to bind dynamic props to dynamic components in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'd like to know how I can iterate a list of component names (which come from an AJAX call to an API server) and render them as components, and pass relevant properties to each component (i.e. bind their properties dynamically).

So far I have managed to iterate a JSON list of items that represent components, and successfully render these components. What I'd like to do now is bind the properties for each component using `v-bind`.

In the example below, the `item-one` component would receive the `image` property with the `item1.jpg` value; and the `item-two` component wouldn't receive any properties.

```
<template>
  <div v-for="item in items">
    <component :is="Object.keys(item)[0]" :v-bind="???"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ItemOne from '../components/item-one'
  import ItemTwo from '../components/item-two'

  export default {
    components: {
      ItemOne,
      ItemTwo
    },
    asyncData () {
      return {
        items: [
          { 'item-one': { 'image': 'item1.jpg' } },
          { 'item-two': { } }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I tried using `:v-bind="Object.values(Object.keys(item)[0])"` but I get the attribute `v-bind="[object Object]"` in the rendered element.

Comment: its just `v-bind`. no colon

Comment: @thanksd that still doesn't work.

Comment: It would be `v-bind="item[Object.keys(item)[0]]"`. Probably would be helpful to change the structure of `items`.

Comment: Yes I was confused about how I might structure this, but I really like the simplicity of your refactoring instead. Much easier to reason about, almost self-explanatory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, you need to get rid of the colon before `v-bind`. The colon is a short-hand for `v-bind` when prefixed to an attribute. But, when passing an object of key pairs to bind, you simply use the `v-bind` directive.

Second, you are not correctly referencing the properties of each item. You can reference them like this:

```
v-bind="item[Object.keys(item)[0]]"
```

---

You wouldn't need to use `Object.keys` if you changed the structure of your `items` property a bit:

```
items: [{ 
  type: 'item-one', 
  props: { 'image': 'item1.jpg' },
}, {
  type: 'item-two',
}]
```

This way, by explicitly labeling the component type and properties beforehand, your template would be much easier to understand:

```
<div v-for="item in items">
  <component :is="item.type" v-bind="item.props"></component>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! Excellent answer, you've made my day. I like the legibility of your refactoring very much and have applied it. I had to remove the colon from the `v-bind` in your answer above though ;-)